# How to get Alt+Tab on active monitor (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: command-line, 18.04, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome, window-manager

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The tab switcher <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only appears on the primary monitor. I would like it to appear on the monitor with the active window, similar to how it functioned in Unity.

Comment: Could you mention if it is the visual switcher or the functionality what you are looking for?

Comment: Visual switcher. I just want to see the switcher on either (a) the active screen or (b) all screens. Currently it just displays on the "primary" screen, which is static in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Gnome-shell, you should have a look at the extension called "[Multi monitor Add-on](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/)"

Here is a screenshot of the feature you may be looking for:

[image]